# how to write query for delete then update

Tags: sql

I have two table person and person history.
both table structure is same...

```
person table
------------
id  name active
1   raj   1
2   arivu 0

person history table
-------------------
id name active
1  raj   1
2  arivu  0
```

i delete record from history table not in person table..
update the person table column active 3....
for example output like

```
person history
-----------
id name active
-------------
1 raj 1
```

then

```
person 
-----
id name active
-----------------
1 raj 1
2 arivu 2
```

Comment: Sorry, but your question is not clear at all. Please express what you really want to do. I can neither find any relation in your example output.

Comment: i have two table like above i delete the record from history table only. if the record deleted from history table means then update main table active column value is whether 0 or 1 is to be 2

Answer (score 0):

Something like this

```
START TRANSACTION
UPDATE person SET active=2 WHERE name='arivu';
DELETE FROM person_history WHERE name='arivu';
COMMIT
```

Comment: but i  need to update the active column value is 2  in person  table can u help me?